# How to populate a text box with data from another .cs files' class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi im so sorry for the generic question i am really new to C#. I am using a previous colleagues code but im looking to populate a textbox on a form with the data from a class.
This is the code for the thing i want to reference

```
public string GetToken(string username, string password) {

            var request = SvcRequest
                            .Get(_url)
                            .WithAuthentication(this.CreateHeader(username, password))
                            .ReturningXml();

            var response = _svc.Send(request);

            return this.ExtractToken(response.Body);
```

I need to populate my text box with `this.ExtractToken(response.Body)`. How do i do this?

Thanks a lot!

Code for main .cs file

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace EbsWebServices

{
    internal sealed class EbsAuthManager
    {
        private readonly string _url;
        private readonly SvcUtility _svc = new SvcUtility();

        public EbsAuthManager()
        {
            _url = "URL_HERE";

            if(!_url.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                _url += "/";
            }
            _url += "Rest/Authentication";
        }

        
        public string GetToken(string username, string password)
        {
            var request = SvcRequest
                .Get(_url)
                .WithAuthentication(this.CreateHeader(username, password))
                .ReturningXml();

            var response = _svc.Send(request);


            return this.ExtractToken(response.Body);
        }
        private string CreateHeader(string username, string password)
        {
            var credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
            var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials));

            return String.Format("Basic {0}", encoded);
        }

        private string ExtractToken (string xml)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            var navigator = doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator();

            var success = navigator
                .SelectChildren("Success", string.Empty)
                .Cast<XPathNavigator>()
                .First();

            var token = navigator
                        .SelectChildren("Token", string.Empty)
                        .Cast<XPathNavigator>()
                        .First();

            return Convert.ToBoolean(success.InnerXml)
                ? token.InnerXml
                : null;


        }

    }
}
```

Code for my form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EbsWebServices;

namespace EBSGetTokenForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an instance of that class inside your form? If so you could do something like this: `textBox.Text = insrance.GetToken("user", "password");`

Comment: @Sascha I have edited my question to show my code

Comment: how do you intend to call `GetToken` I don't see it in the Form1 class

Comment: @MongZhu i want to do all the calling outside the form then just pass in the value of `return this.ExtractToken(response.Body);` to the form

Comment: Can i store the value of `return this.ExtractToken(response.Body);` in a public variable that i can set the textbox value to that variable?